# Ajax: How to output data for Jquery autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to use Jquery's Autocomplete from here http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

But my output is not working with it.

[Here's my FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/JbPpM/) I had to manually insert the json into an array as JsFiddle doesn't allow outside database's...

PHP:

```
<?php 
  include('../../dbconn.php');
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Example php script for fetching data from mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $databaseName = "accounting";
  $tableName = "generalTransactions";

  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 1) Connect to mysql database
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $con = mysql_connect($gaSql['server'],$gaSql['user'],$gaSql['password']);
  $dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 2) Query database for data
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ");          //query
  $array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                          //fetch result                          
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // 3) echo result as json 
  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Ajax in Fiddle:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        ["23","1500-0900","Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","Income Statement","Other Income","","","2013-07-26 10:22:07","Demo Admin"],
        ["13","1500-0920","Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","Income Statement","Other Income","","","2013-07-23 13:42:45","Demo Admin"],
        ["14","3100-1200","Other Assets 002 - Owned - Depreciation","Income Statement","Expenditure","Depreciation","","2013-07-23 13:47:06","Demo Admin"],
        ["12","3200-1120","Other Assets 001 - Leased - Depreciation","Income Statement 3","Expenditure","Depreciation","","2013-07-23 13:48:42","Demo Admin"],
        ["16","3300-0800","Bank Charges","Income Statement","Expenditure","","","2013-07-25 10:27:16","Demo Admin"],
        ["15","3300-4100","Loss On Sale Of Fixed Assets","Income Statement","Expenditure","","","2013-07-25 10:27:08","Demo Admin"],
        ["21","3300-5500","Rental - Premises","Income Statement","Expenditure","","","2013-07-25 10:27:53","Demo Admin"],
        ["20","3300-6800","Transport And Freight","Income Statement","Expenditure","","","2013-07-25 10:27:47","Demo Admin"],
        ["22","6500-5100","Goodwill - Impairment","Balance Sheet","Non-Current Assets","Goodwill","","2013-07-25 10:28:00","Demo Admin"],
        ["17","7400-0100","Interbank Transfer","Balance Sheet","Current Assets","Cash And Cash Equivalents","","2013-07-25 10:27:22","Demo Admin"],
        ["18","7400-0200","Bank Balance 001","Balance Sheet","Current Assets","Cash And Cash Equivalents","","2013-07-25 10:27:29","Demo Admin"],
        ["19","9800-0100","Taxation - Normal","Balance Sheet","Current Liabilities","Taxation","","2013-07-25 10:27:40","Demo Admin"]
    ];
    $( "#account" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Ajax in my file:

```
$( "#account" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php'
});
```

I dont think my output is correct...

If you have any answers or suggestions, I'll really appreciate it!

**UPDATE:**

New output using `mysql_fetch_accoc`

```
[{"id":"23","accountNumber":"1500-0900","accountDescription":"Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Other Income","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-26 10:22:07","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"13","accountNumber":"1500-0920","accountDescription":"Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Other Income","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:42:45","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"14","accountNumber":"3100-1200","accountDescription":"Other Assets 002 - Owned - Depreciation","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"Depreciation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:47:06","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"12","accountNumber":"3200-1120","accountDescription":"Other Assets 001 - Leased - Depreciation","accountLevel1":"Income Statement 3","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"Depreciation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:48:42","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"16","accountNumber":"3300-0800","accountDescription":"Bank Charges","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:16","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"15","accountNumber":"3300-4100","accountDescription":"Loss On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:08","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"21","accountNumber":"3300-5500","accountDescription":"Rental - Premises","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:53","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"20","accountNumber":"3300-6800","accountDescription":"Transport And Freight","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:47","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"22","accountNumber":"6500-5100","accountDescription":"Goodwill - Impairment","accountLevel1":"Balance Sheet","accountLevel2":"Non-Current Assets","accountLevel3":"Goodwill","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:28:00","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"17","accountNumber":"7400-0100","accountDescription":"Interbank Transfer","accountLevel1":"Balance Sheet","accountLevel2":"Current Assets","accountLevel3":"Cash And Cash Equivalents","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:22","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"18","accountNumber":"7400-0200","accountDescription":"Bank Balance 001","accountLevel1":"Balance Sheet","accountLevel2":"Current Assets","accountLevel3":"Cash And Cash Equivalents","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:29","createdUser":"Demo Admin"},{"id":"19","accountNumber":"9800-0100","accountDescription":"Taxation - Normal","accountLevel1":"Balance Sheet","accountLevel2":"Current Liabilities","accountLevel3":"Taxation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:40","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}]
```

**Edit:**

```
[{"id":"23","accountNumber":"1500-0900","accountDescription":"Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Other Income","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-26 10:22:07","createdUser":"Demo Admin","label":"1500-0900","value":"23"}]
```

Comment: Could I get you to change `$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);` to `$array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` and show me what the resulting **availableTags** looks like??? Thanks!

Comment: @DevlshOne I changed it, the json looks better! Please see my update! Please let me know what I can do to the autocomplete labels and values to get them?

Comment: MUCH BETTER! Now let me show you how to use it...

Comment: Do your magic @DevlshOne

Comment: Give me just a few minutes to assemble the jsFiddle.

Comment: Ok, one more change.. please change `"SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 "` to: **`"SELECT *, accountNumber AS label, id AS value FROM $tableName ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 "`**

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35581/discussion-between-devlshone-and-msbodetti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this two ways:

a) Your output needs to be massaged so that it is looking for what the Autocomplete script needs to display; **OR**
b) You can modify the response from the `search.php` script within the Autocomplete options top make it work.

Either way, the reply from `search.php` needs to be an associative array, so please change `mysql_fetch_row` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`. We're going to use the first way {a} and make it fabulous!

Now, let's look at what the Autocomplete script needs in order to work. You are returning what appears to be an array of objects:

```
var AvailableTags = 
{"id":"23","accountNumber":"1500-0900","accountDescription":"Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Other Income","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-26 10:22:07","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
{"id":"13","accountNumber":"1500-0920","accountDescription":"Profit On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Other Income","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:42:45","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
{"id":"14","accountNumber":"3100-1200","accountDescription":"Other Assets 002 - Owned - Depreciation","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"Depreciation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:47:06","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
{"id":"12","accountNumber":"3200-1120","accountDescription":"Other Assets 001 - Leased - Depreciation","accountLevel1":"Income Statement 3","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"Depreciation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-23 13:48:42","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
{"id":"16","accountNumber":"3300-0800","accountDescription":"Bank Charges","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:16","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
{"id":"15","accountNumber":"3300-4100","accountDescription":"Loss On Sale Of Fixed Assets","accountLevel1":"Income Statement","accountLevel2":"Expenditure","accountLevel3":"","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:08","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}
...
{"id":"19","accountNumber":"9800-0100","accountDescription":"Taxation - Normal","accountLevel1":"Balance Sheet","accountLevel2":"Current Liabilities","accountLevel3":"Taxation","accountLevel4":"","createdDate":"2013-07-25 10:27:40","createdUser":"Demo Admin"}]
```

Unfortnately, these objects are missing two key identifiers to tell the Autocomplete script how to use them properly. The *item* and *value* keys. These keys tell Autocomplete which parts of your responses to display in the input box and which to use as a value for that selection. For instance, in your example (below), we will need to assign two elements of your returning objects an *item* key and a *value* key - a pair of these for each of the objects in your returned array.

```
$( "#account" ).autocomplete({
    source: 'search.php'
})
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/JbPpM/2/)  (Almost there!)

Comment: Ah I see, the json output is adding `label` and `value`.. so the autocomplete can find it?

Comment: I got it working http://jsfiddle.net/JbPpM/5/ With the last Select you gave me to add `label` and `value`.Thanks, will accept your answer :)

Comment: Excellent! Great job!

Comment: Thanks @DevlshOne but can I ask something.. is it possible to put two database columns as `label`, so can it be something like this `SELECT *, accountNumber AND accountDescription AS label, accountNumber AS value FROM $tableName ORDER BY id ASC` I tried that but it doesn't work..

Comment: You mean so that you could search by either accountNumber OR accountDescription? Only if you were using the actual search `term` option... **"SELECT *, accountNumber AS label, id AS value WHERE accountNumber like '" . $term . "%' OR accountDescription like '" . $term . "%'**